Как сделать Google переводчик на сайте
Думаю Вы все знаете про google-переводчик, либо любой другой переводчик.
Я хочу добавить google-переводчик на свой сайт, чтобы через него переводить текст с русского на кыргызский.
Как это можно реализовать, чтобы было два input поля, и в один вводился текст на русском, а в другом выводился на кыргызском.

Ищете Google переводчик API, регистрируете ключ, подключаете к себе на сайт и всё готово.
Если не хотите тратить деньги, можно использовать API от Яндекса, тоже неплохо переводит. Уверен, ваш кыргызкий там тоже есть.
Если принципиально Google, вот бесплатное решение.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
